# Mapping change - is data lost?

Tags: elasticsearch

My teammate has changed definition of mapping because we have out of memmory error on sorting, and searching without sorting works fine. And he read somewhere that this could be problem with doc_values setting. Unfortunatelly without reading any other documentation about mappings. We have 1 index and mapping of 2 types. Couple fields in both mappings has same names. Our data structure and changes can be explained by schema:

Before change:

```
type A: {
    properties: {
        aaa: { type: string, store: true }
        bbb: { type: long, store: true }
        ccc: { type: long, store: true }
    }
},
type B: {
    properties: {
        aaa: { type: string, store: true }
        bbb: { type: long, store: true }
        xxx: { type: long, store: true }
    }
}
```

After change:

```
type A: {
    properties: {
        aaa: { type: string, store: true,
            fields: {
                raw: { type: string, index: not_analyzed, doc_values: true }
            }
        }
        bbb: { type: long, store: true, doc_values: true }
        ccc: { type: long, store: true, doc_values: true }
    }
},
type B: {
    properties: {
        aaa: { type: string, store: true }
        bbb: { type: long, store: true }
        xxx: { type: long, store: true }
    }
}
```

So he added doc_values and changed one field existing in both types to multifield but he changed mapping only for one type.

Documentation states:

1. Changing mapping of existing field is forbidden unless you are prepared to reindex all data but in other article I've read ([changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime)) there is one exception: upgrade field to multifield.
2. Fields in different types having same name across same index are shared and must have the same mapping.
3. All fields which support doc_values have them enabled by default. Doc values are supported on almost all field types, with the notable exception of analyzed string fields.

And after all I'm not sure with what we ended up. I know typeA became unserchable, all queries gives us no results. But typeB still works fine.

Is explicitly defining 'doc_type: true' really a forbidden change of existing field (if the field has this setting as default)?

Is convering a analyzed string field to multifield with changing behaviour of doc_values from not supported to true (because subfield is not_analyzed) forbidden change of existing field or not?

Is index permanently corrupted or changes can be undone. How? By changing typeA to former settings (which I'm not sure if help or destroy index if it isn't destroyed yet) or by changing typeB to fit typeA. I don't want to change anything so careless as my teammate because reindexing 6 bilions of documents isn't option I like...

Comment: that's very odd, are you sure you're using the same query? basically these changes do not change anything, multifield just adds new rev.index for `raw` field. I would experiment like this: create new index with the original mapping, index few documents, check queries, perform mapping changes like you described, check queries again

Comment: First of all - one good point - you aren't sure how something works - test on some test data. Second - of course people can make mistakes.Suppose I run wrong querries. But both of us? Unlikely. But even you're right - we have two beta state apps based on that data. (One of them unfortunatelly is public beta). Algoritms haven't change. Worked before. Don't work now. One type is broken. And I probably know why. Assume changes didn't invalidate index cause it changes nothing. But mappings of shared field isn't the same. Does Elastic knows that not identical mappings technically are the same?

Comment: I suppose the problem is - Elasic doesn't know that mappings are compatibile (drives to the same after all but definition differs) And Elastic "thinks" that mapping violate rules. And one of the types doesn't work. Unification od mappings is needed and I would do it but I'm not sure of effects. I have to ways. The "safer" - restore typeA which is already broken can definitly kill index (multifield back to field) and prove that "safer" was an illusion, change typeB to be the same as typeA is putting at risk something that still works. It seems tests are inevitable :-)